# Convert Unix timestamps to user's local time using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a list of international events with their start dates stored in unix timestamp format. I would like to convert these to the user's local time using moment.js. I am attempting to do this using:

```
var example_utc = 1628946000;

// GMT: Saturday, August 14, 2021 1:00:00 PM
// Your time zone: Saturday, August 14, 2021 2:00:00 PM GMT+01:00 DST
// Relative: In 6 days

moment(example_utc);
```

However, this returns:

```
Mon Jan 19 1970 20:19:37 GMT+0000
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fisrt of all you need to get it as unix as momentJs right way. Then you can convert it as localDate by using .local() or automatic (situational):

```
var example_utc = 1628946000;
var momentStyle = moment.unix(example_utc);
var localDate = moment(momentStyle).local();
alert(localDate); // Sat Aug 14 2021 17:00:00 GMT+0400
```

Also note that if your original input contains a time zone offset such as +00:00 or Z, you don't need to use .utc() or .local().

```
var example_utc = 1628946000;
var localDate = moment.unix(example_utc);
alert(localDate); // Sat Aug 14 2021 17:00:00 GMT+0400
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the UNIX timestamp to 1000 to convert it to milliseconds because javascript `Date` works on milliseconds [refer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?milliseconds#the_ecmascript_epoch_and_timestamps)

```
var example_utc = 1628946000;

moment(example_utc*1000); // Saturday, August 14, 2021 1:00:00 PM
```